# IE Conditional Statements only working on home page?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I'm using a conditional statement/stylesheet because my client wants a CSS3 modal window for login, which (of course) won't work natively in IE due to pointer-events. The modal window code is in the footer.

I created an ie.css stylesheet & added the following to the header.php file:

```
<!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('ie.css'); ?>" media="screen" />   <![endif]-->
```

I/m pretty sure the stylesheet is fine, and (in theory) the command is fine, because it works on the home page. The problem is I can't get it to work on any other page. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

To see the issue in action, [go here](http://bit.ly/10YLBqd).

Comment: Can't find an ie.css getting loaded in the home page. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css"
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed!  That one little change in syntax from the other answers totally seems to have fixed it. I hope there's no issue going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a code like this `<![endif]-->` at the end of your line code? Maybe if you remove that it will work fine.

Comment: What did you understand? Do you know what are conditional comments? Learn about it and answer. [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: @Sitepor, that is the closing tag for the conditional statement. Leaving it out would mess up the markup.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it is getting loaded this way:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ayurvega" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

The code is specifying the `href` attribute incorrectly, pointing to: `ayurvega.com/main/Ayurvega`, which is not the right one. Guess you need to replace it with something like:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

Or, this one, may be...

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Praveen. Neither of them have worked yet. There must be something I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
<!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" />   <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Reigel. Unfortunately, it's a no go.

Comment: @OrenIshii, if you view your source, you can see something wrong, like this `<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->` your href is not pointing to the right link...